# How to allow only positive integer input from user?

Tags: c++, input, iostream

I have been trying to **only allow positive integer input** into my program. But works it is getting past with the *character* input and *negative integers*, *decimal numbers*. Any ideas how to fix that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int row, col, i, i1, j, test;
    double n;
    test = 0;

    while (test == 0) 
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of rows: " << endl;
        cin >> row;
        if (cin.fail() || row <= 0 || !(row == (int)row)) 
        {
            cout << "\nEntered value is wrong!";
            printf("\n");
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            test = 0;
        }
        else {  test = 1;  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some compilable code.

Comment: `>>` stops at the first invalid character. You need to check that character to know if it's the proper end of your input.

Comment: `!(row==(int)row)` is completely useless and redundant.

Comment: Additional tips: put `cout << "\nEntered value is wrong!\n";` instead of `cout << "\nEntered value is wrong!";` 
    `printf("\n");` Also, try to use either one of `endl` or `\n`,not both.

Comment: What's the point of "`else{
    parbaude =1;
}`" ?

Comment: if (row mod 1 != 0) then row is not divisible by 1

Answer (score 1):

> I have been trying to only allow positive integer input into my
>   program.

You can easily check it with the help of *[std::isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)*, if you take the user **input as a string instead of an integer**.

1. take the user input as a *string*.
2. for each character in the string, check whether it is a digit (using `std::isdigit`).
3. if any of the char's in the user input(which is a string) is not a valid digit, return the boolean = *false*.
4. if its true for all chars, the *input* is an integer and you can convert it back to integer using *[std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)*.

Following is a sample code:
<kbd>[SEE LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EwO68lx9i1EEUPNH)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> // std::isdigit
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool isInteger(const std::string& input)
{
    for (const char eachChar : input)
        if (!std::isdigit(eachChar))
            return false;  // if not a digit, return  False
    return true; 
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> inputs{ "123", "-54", "8.5", "45w" }; // some inputs as strings
    for(const std::string& input: inputs)
    {
        if (isInteger(input))
        {
            // apply std::stoi(input) to convert string input to integer
            std::cout << "Input is a valid integer: " << input << std::endl;
        }
        else {  std::cout << input << " is not a valid integer!\n"; }
    }
}
```

**output**:

```
Input is a valid integer: 123
-54 is not a valid integer!
8.5 is not a valid integer!
45w is not a valid integer!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you probably want (**[demo](https://www.ideone.com/vs2fGY)**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  int n;
  while ( !( cin >> n ) || n < 0 )
  {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
  }

  //...

  return 0;
}
```